# What data structures/algorithms to efficiently substitute DNF expressions into each other?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, boolean, sat, dnf

I'm trying to work with a system that has a few hundred boolean literals with relations between them in disjunctive normal form (e.g. `x1 = (x2 & x3) | x4`; `x2 = x5 | x6`; etc). I want to simplify the system by substituting some of these into all the others (I already know roughly the substitutions that are tractable). But so far I've run into very poor scaling from my data structures. I'm representing an expression as a `Set` of `BitSet`s, which eliminates outright duplicates, but I still end up (seemingly) wasting a ton of time building these sets because I want to eagerly prune out any redundant disjuncts - e.g. `(x1 & x2) | (x1 & x2 & x3)` is just `(x1 & x2)`.

Is there a better way to store or manipulate these that doesn't incur an O(n^2) cost just to build them?

Comment: The number of distinct BitSets n for x literals is already O(2^x) and because there are duplicates n can be infinite. You can eliminate the redundancies by pairwise OR and compare which would be O(xn^2), but remember how big n can be... hard to optimize.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I'm running into. n is getting large. I'd also be fine with something that isn't necessarily the simplest form possible, but it's within a constant factor, and/or can be incrementally improved, so that it improves with roasted access (though maybe the only reason to access something is to substitute in somewhere else or be substituted into, and in both cases I probably really do want it more simplified, rather than less).